# Add Appendix to TOC without a pagenumber

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, appendices

I want my Appendix, Glossary and Bibliography in the TOC without a pagenumber but clickable. When the user click on the name of one of theses, it should jump to the specific chapter.

For the appendix I want, that there is no page numbering, how could I turn this off? I'm not using the fancyhdr package.

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,smallheadings,parident, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{color}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\typearea{12}
\pagestyle{headings}

\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\small}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
%Bibliogrpahy
\bibliography{./literatur/literaturverzeichnis.bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}

%Glossary
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Glossar}
\printglossaries
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar}

%Appendix
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\addchap{Anhang}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\section*{Klassendiagramm} \label{class-diagram}
\section*{Liste mit verwendeten UI-Elementen} \label{list-ui-elements}
\section*{Quelltext} \label{source-code}
\section*{Abbildungen}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\addchap*` instead of `\addchap`. In that case you might have to take care of the page header entry yourself, using `\chaptermark` or `\markboth`. Further you can call `\addtocontents`. In contrast to `\addcontentsline`, it doesn't show the page number by default. You need to take care of the formatting of the TOC entry, for this you can use `\usekomafont{chapterentry}`. Further I added the hyperlink manually below. `\protect` is required, for preventing the expansion of the commands which are written to the .toc file.

```
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{link.appendix}{}
\addchap*{Anhang}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\usekomafont{chapterentry}%
  \protect\hyperlink{link.appendix}{Anhang}}
```

If you need this way several times, you could create a macro for this kind of chapter.